# cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, tag-handler

I am using tag handler plugin for my website. and I placed the supportive js beneath the js of mine where I am initializing the method. And every js is in footer. I don't know why i am getting this error.

Here is js:

```
$("#array_tag_handler").tagHandler({
    assignedTags: [ 'C', 'Perl', 'PHP' ],
    availableTags: [ 'C', 'C++', 'C#', 'Java', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'Python' ],
    autocomplete: true
});
```

I placed this in `document.ready`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to include the JQUERY library to your project otherwise it would not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
   // ...everything in here is jquery include jquery library..
    });
```

download jquery and add to project in your head

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script scr="jquery.min.js"></script> 
 // to your directory tree 
   </head>
```

Comment: I would put it all in my head 1.jquery 2.jquery plugin 3.my script.js,